# Is BroadcastReceiver asynchronous enough to make this work

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, blocking

Wanted to stop a thread doing some downloads.
The code below work fine when i only have the `stopNow = true;` and no blocking occur.
I create the `boolean stopNow = false;` as a field in my IntentService.

Since `stopNow` only work when the connection is ongoing in the `while` loop
but it does not work if f.ex connection stales and start to block.

I wanted to add this code to really stop the blocking.

```
if(socket != null){
    socket.shutdownOutput();
    socket.shutdownInput();
}
```

The question is if this is asynchronous so if the execution is ongoing in the
 `while` loop the `stopNow = true;` will stop it and i can put a sleep(5000) after the `stopNow = true;`  and then the `if(socket != null)` will be true only if the `stopNow` had no effect.

hope you follow me..

`BroadcastReceiver`  that are located inside the `run()`:

```
private class MyIncomingListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if(intent.getAction().equals(Consts.COM_CARLSBERG_STOPOUTGOING)) {
            String b = intent.getStringExtra(Consts.COM_CARLSBERG_BATCHUUID);
            if(b != null){
                if(b.equals(batch.batchUuid)){
                    stopNow = true;
                    // sleep(5000) wait for stopNow to take effect
                    // if socket=null then stopNow did it's job
                    // if socket is alive then there is blocking to unblock
                try{
                    if(socket != null){
                        socket.shutdownOutput();
                        socket.shutdownInput();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {}
               }    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is actually working good so far

```
    stopNow = true;

try{
    if(socket != null){
        socket.shutdownOutput();
        socket.shutdownInput();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

Answer (score -1):

> 

```
public final void stop ()
Since: API Level 1
This method is deprecated.
because stopping a thread in this manner is unsafe and can leave your application and the VM in an unpredictable state.

Requests the receiver Thread to stop and throw ThreadDeath. The Thread is resumed if it was suspended and awakened if it was sleeping, so that it can proceed to throw ThreadDeath.



 try {
                     int waited = 0;
                     while(_active && (waited < _splashTime)) {
                         sleep(100);
                         if(_active) {
                             waited += 100;
                         }
                     }
                 } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                     // do nothing
                 } finally {
                     finish();
                     Intent intent= new Intent(SplashActivity.this,LoginViewController.class);
                     startActivity(intent);

                     stop();
                 }
```